# Python/React Webpack (webpack-cli) "ERROR: ENOENT: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, reactjs, webpack

I am attempting to run a standard, `npm run dev` using pipenv shell, python but I'm running into something strange.

Now there is an important point to make note of, and that is that while I was doing some work previously, I saw that I had misnamed one of my directories, so I moved the 'main.js' file into one directory, made an update to the directory structure, and then deposited the file 'main.js' back into the appropriate folder.

When I run the `npm run dev` command, I am receiving this error:

```
> lead-manager@1.0.0 dev2
> webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/scripts/index.js -o ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js

[webpack-cli] [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Steph\python_tuts\lead-manager\leadmanager\frontend\static\frontend\main.js\main.js'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Steph\\python_tuts\\lead-manager\\leadmanager\\frontend\\static\\frontend\\main.js\\main.js'
}
```

While I can understand that the directory change that I made might have an effect that would result in this situation, as you can see from the second line of the feedback from the console and comparing to the error, the command and the error are not directed towards the same directory.

I can't find the reason why the error that is being returned is being directed to the non-existent deleted directory. You'll notice that there is a double ref to main.js `..frontend\\main.js\\main.js`

For the life of me, I've dug around the application I've written so far, and that reflects a previous state of the application. I have no idea why it is still trying to go there.

Below you'll find the complete contents of the file `package.json`. However, I've also attached a link to the [repo in my github](https://github.com/Smith-Steve/Lead-Manager).

```
{
  "name": "lead-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Steve Smith - Python/React Tutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js -o ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js -o ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have a hunch this is something fairly simple, please advise.